# how to change serialization of a Doctrine Entity's attribute programmatically

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, symfony-2.8, jms-serializer

I have a `Dashboard` Entity properly serialized/deserialized by JMSSerializer (through JMSSerializerBundle):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="dashboard", schema="myappID")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Belka\MyBundle\Entity\Repository\DashboardRepository")
 */
class Dashboard
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue("SEQUENCE")
     *
     * @Serializer\Groups({"o-all", "o-all-getCDashboard", "i-p2-editDashboard"})
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Belka\MyBundle\Entity\User")
     *
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_dashboards_associated",
     *      schema="myAppID",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="dashboard_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     *
     * @Serializer\groups({
     *     "o-p2-create",
     *     "i-p2-create",
     *     "o-p2-patch",
     *     "i-p2-editDashboard"
     * })
     */
    protected $users;
}
```

and I'm using JMSSerializer's `jms_serializer.doctrine_object_constructor` as object constructor.
Everything works like charm, but I have the following corner case: sometimes I have to set `Dashboard::$users` as a string (i.e. when the client sends a semantic-incorrect `users` property, after my checks I return the object along with a string in order to inform it. This is pretty convenient for the front-end apps). 
JMSSerializer [takes advantage of the Doctrine's annotation](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/configuration#configuring-metadata-locations), but in this case I really would like to override it programmatically, since is a very corner-case. Two are the ways on my mind:

1. Is there a way in order to set the `SerializationContext` to map `Dashboard::$users` as a string property?
2. Is there a way in order to change the Doctrine's Metadata before serializing it?
3. Other options I didn't realize?

Any piece of suggestion is more than welcome

Comment: Maybe via [events](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/event_system)?

Comment: @Veve I guess you were right. Take a look at my own anser :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution, although it does not consider nested entities's properties (has-a relations). That would mean visiting the whole graph, but I did not find the time to study the guts of the excellent JMSSSerializer. It works perfectly for forcing the first-level entity's properties though:

first-off, a `pre-serialize` subscriber is needed. It will cycle over protected properties and checks if they contain a string. Is so, the type for the serialization will be overridden.

```
class SerializationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    static public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            array('event' => 'serializer.pre_serialize', 'method' => 'onPreserialize'),
        );
    }

    public function onPreSerialize(PreSerializeEvent $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getObject();
        $metadata = $event->getContext()->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataForClass($event->getType()['name']);
        $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($entity);
        $props = $reflect->getProperties(\ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED);

        foreach ($props as $prop) {
            $prop->setAccessible(true);

            if (is_string($prop->getValue($entity))) {
                // here is the magic
                $metadata->propertyMetadata[$prop->name]->type = array('name' => 'string', 'params' => array());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I didn't want to listen to this each time I serialize something. This is a corner case within one of my services. We can take advantage of the `JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher::addSubscriber`, although the `EventDispatcher` service is declared `private`.
So, let's turn that service into `public` through a *compiler pass* so as to take advantage of `addSubscriber`:

```
class MyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideJmsSerializerEventDispatcherDefPass());
    }
}
```

... and let's turn that service into a `public` one

```
class OverrideJmsSerializerEventDispatcherDefPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('jms_serializer.event_dispatcher');
        $definition->setPublic(true);
    }
}
```

Hence, we can inject it into our services. I.e. in  my `services.yml`:

```
  belka.mybundle.dashboardhandler:
      class: Belka\MyBundle\Handlers\DashboardHandler
      calls:
          - [setEventDispatcher, ["@jms_serializer.event_dispatcher"]]
```

Alright, now we can easily add our subscriber whenever we need to, without the burden of another listener each time my application is performing a serialization:

```
$serializationSubscriber = new SerializationSubscriber();
$this->eventDispatcher->addSubscriber($serializationSubscriber);
```

Feel free to complete the answer with a solution that visits the whole Entities' graph. That would be great.